# Ruby protect decrypted file

Tags: ruby

Currently , I have an encrypted file. When the application starts, it runs the " decrypt" so that another application can read the file.

This other application reads the file from the directory .

How can I protect the file was decrypted ?
The decrypted file is played in the folder to be read . I need the file is not visible , so that people do not copy.

Decrypt code:

```
if File.exist?(RubyCryptoPath) 
 # decryption
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
cipher.decrypt
cipher.key = "1234123412341235kpoaskpoaskopsakpoaskpokasopasopkpoaspoaksops"
cipher.iv = "1234klsaposakpoaskpoaskpoaskpoaskpoaskopaskposakpoas" # key and iv are the ones from above

buf = ""
File.open("Game.rgss3a", "wb") do |outf|
  File.open("Game.wingscript", "rb") do |inf|
    while inf.read(4096, buf)
      outf << cipher.update(buf)
    end
    outf << cipher.final
  end
end

end
```

Comment: What means: `How can I protect the file was decrypted ?`

Comment: The decrypted file is played in the folder to be read . I need the file is not visible , so that people do not copy .

Comment: So `Game.rgss3a` is your decrypted file, and you want to somehow prevent access? However, anyone can just read your script (it is in the same file system) and figure out how to get the data directly from `Game.wingscript`. It is not secure.

Comment: But is there any way to avoid the access to the decrypted file ?

Comment: @user3571412 - no, unless your script is running as a privileged user, and the person trying to access the file is accessing as a different user? If this is code running locally, under a user's control, then this security model cannot be made to work, because the user can do (and undo) anything the script can do.

Comment: So, I can include a file with a exe, using ocra for ruby?

Comment: A self-extracting exe it is also insecure, but **might** hide/obscure some of the files from casual hacking, which I guess is what you are trying to achieve? However, if you are feeding the resultant file to another application *outside* of your exe, then that won't work very well either - the decrypted file will still be visible from where the other application loads it from.

Comment: In fact , the application is a DLL. So I could include it together.

Comment: You could, but someone who knew how `ocra` worked could easily get the decrypted data. It might put a small barrier for someone who didn't know.

Comment: So, how I can make this?

Comment: Ask a separate question about what you are making, and what you have tried. As it stands, I have no idea what you are making, all I can say is that you *cannot protect a data file in a stand-alone application if you send it encrypted or packaged to a client, along with the all the tools and data required to decrypt and/or unpack it*.